# Faker ID number with flexible format

Tags: ruby, faker

I'm looking for a way to generate codes/ids in my specs. I found [barcodes](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/barcode.md), [codes](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/code.md), and [id numbers](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/doc/default/id_number.md). None of these quite fit my purpose...or if I use them they will be misleading for the type of code I'm actually generating. Is there a generator that allows for a format specifier? For example, I'd like to generate a string with digits and dashes in a specified sequence, like `#####-###-####-#####`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faker's `numerify`, `letterify`, and `bothify` seem like what you're looking for:

```rb
Faker::Base.numerify('###-###') # "203-099"
Faker::Base.letterify('???-???') # "ADB-VMZ"
Faker::Base.bothify('???-###') # "ISE-485"
```

[Docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/faker-ruby/faker/master/Faker/Base#bothify-class_method)